# Asp.net localization - short key vs full text as name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently facing the problem that I want to get a value in English and its translated version at the same time. But since "WithCulture" of "IStringLocalizer" is deprecated, i would have to read the resource file manually.

However, while researching for a solution, I came across a general dilemma.

For the translation I use resource files (e.g. IndexModel.en-US.resx).

Many tutorials rely on short key values such as @Localizer["HelloText"] in a view, which translates to "Welcome to my homepage".

However, you can see in the Microsoft documentation that they sometimes use the full English version as the name, so in this example @Localizer["Welcome to my homepage"].

I can see that the Microsoft example always outputs a readable text if the translation does not work.

However, the big disadvantage is that if the text is changed, not only the resource file has to be adapted, but also every place in the code where this text is used.

Hence the question. Which of these is best practice and why?

I need help in deciding what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the big disadvantage is that if the text is changed, not only
> the resource file has to be adapted, but also every place in the code
> where this text is used.
>
> Hence the question. Which of these is best practice and why?

Well, I am  not sure if you have gone through [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/best-practices-for-developing-world-ready-apps#localization-best-practices) regarding the [localization implemnetational guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/best-practices-for-developing-world-ready-apps#localization-best-practices).

Although, best practice completely depends on the scenario and business requirement, however, if you have gone through the official document, you would seen, it has following guidelines:

First of all, as you may know  short keys are typically faster to type and easier to manage, especially when there are many localized strings in the application. However, it might not as descriptive as English full text as the name provides immediate clarity.

Another important point is that, short keys are maintainable, because If the text needs to be changed, you only need to update the resource file, without having to modify the code where the localized string is used.

But here's the main downsides for English full text of a localized string changes, it requires updating not only the resource file but also every place in the code where the string is used, which can be time-consuming and error-prone.

So, you could keep these things in mind, for most scenarios, using short keys is preferable due to its efficiency, maintainability, and consistency benefits. You should consider English full text when user experience,clarity and fallback readability become your first priority.

I personally used the hybrid approach depending on my needs. I have last time implemented in following way:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "IViewLocalizer";
}

@inject IViewLocalizer ViewLocalizer

<div class="text-center">
    <p>@ViewLocalizer["ViewGreeting"]</p>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Defined in form culture:

`asp-route-culture=@ViewData["culture"]`

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If maintainability become your first concern then go with the [SortKey class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.sortkey?view=net-8.0) but if you want focus on clarity and transparency then you could choose the English full text. But then again, I would sill suggest you to consider your scenario and requirement. Please [refer to this official document for better understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/best-practices-for-developing-world-ready-apps#localization-best-practices).

Comment: I have read the official document, but for [aspnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-8.0) not dotnet. As you can see there was no "best practice" guide. There they use fulltext like "<p>@Localizer["Use this area to provide additional information."]</p>" where as the dotnet guide uses short keys like "localizer["GreetingMessage"]". But this makes sense, as the dotnet guide tells that it is best practice to have the translations in separate resource only dll's, which would be difficult to achieve with full text

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah correct, you got it right.